# how to improve POST send speed in struts2 of large forms

Tags: java, performance, post, struts2

I have a web application in java with struts2 using a form with a spreadsheet to complete data. When you press save data is sent by post, using submit (). on the server struts convert to object with the following structure:

```
Header object
    Data…
    Array<Row objects>
```

The problem we have is that it is very slow sending post data until it receives the response. Moreover, the problem is between the sending of the data, using POST, and when struts convert it.

How can we solve this problem?

Comment: I have no idea from your example what the data structure being created looks like. What is the size of the post request (in bytes) and the response time? What response time would you like to see? Can you provide an example of the post response -- e.g., what fields are being sent, etc.?

Comment: the size of the post if 12200 bytes aprox, it takes aprox 2051 ms. i would like to see 450 ms aprox, the post has aprox 90 text fields

Comment: Split the page in tabs, or split the "save" operations per-section asyncronously (with Ajax). It would be transparent to the user. 90 are a lot of fields, this go against the usability :| (I Know you probably have already set up everything and have no time to change it... just theoretically speaking, for the next time).

Comment: you're right but many fields are completed on the user usage so only a small group of the field are filed by the user and the other are filed automatic or edit by the user. how can i split it using ajax? i send it rows by rows or using another method?

Comment: Row by row seems a fine approach, if this is an online spreadsheet. What if user has completed 89 out of 90 rows, and the power goes away ? Let's split the logic... you could even save (better if persistent) "drafts", then retrieve them serverside when the user says he's finish its work and want to save it. So you will send one row at a time, and will save them all at once at the end with no delays.

Comment: i will try this adding autosave features row by row